# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2005 Express account with sa

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005-express

I was trying to connect to my SQL Server 2005 Express instance with the `sa` account but I can access to other instance with `sa`.

Please let me know how to connect how to connect to SQL Server Express instance with `sa` account.

I have tried this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/35505/cant-connect-to-sql-server-using-sa-account-what-im-missing) but in vain.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `sa` account is disabled in your case. Try to login to sql server with (windows auth) login which you was using for installation and enable `sa` login

Another thing  - check if SQL Server authentication mode is **SQL Server and Windows**.

Comment: Thanks for the response but sa login is enabled too.

Comment: Well (if you remember the pass) you should have access. Otherwise you can reset the sa password. There are no specific issues with sa in Express editions.

Comment: By the way every SQL Server instance has its own sa account and there should not be any relationships with other instances